# Haskell FFI Support for Functions With Variadic Arguments

Tags: haskell, ffi, variadic-functions

Can anyone show me an example of using a C function with variadic arguments (e.g. `printf`) with Haskell's Foreign Function Interface? I tried searching the HaskellWiki, but found no such examples.

Thanks!

Comment: You could look at how `printf` is called from Haskell (in the `Printf-TH` or `printf-mauke` packages).

Comment: @TomMD: I'm pretty sure both of those are just reinventions in Haskell of the printf concept, not bindings to the C implementation.

Comment: @mokus: Ah, thanks.  I thought it farmed out the work under the hood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Haskell interface to libffi (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/libffi), as in this code copied verbatim out of a project I'm working on (you can see it in context at https://github.com/mokus0/bindings-hdf5/blob/master/src/Bindings/HDF5/Raw/H5E.hsc).  This particular function also checks for the no-arguments case and calls the C function directly when possible to avoid the small overhead associated with libffi.

```
-- libffi to the rescue!  I have no idea how I'd wrap this without it, and there
-- doesn't appear to be a non-deprecated non-private non-varargs equivalent.
-- 
-- |Pushes a new error record onto error stack for the current
-- thread.  The error has major and minor IDs 'maj_id' and
-- 'min_id', the name of a function where the error was detected,
-- the name of the file where the error was detected, the
-- line within that file, and an error description string.  The
-- function name, file name, and error description strings must
-- be statically allocated.
-- 
-- Returns non-negative on success/Negative on failure.
-- 
-- > herr_t H5Epush2(hid_t err_stack, const char *file, const char *func, unsigned line,
-- >     hid_t cls_id, hid_t maj_id, hid_t min_id, const char *msg, ...);
--
-- (msg is a printf format string, the varargs are the format parameters)
h5e_push2 :: HId_t -> CString -> CString -> CUInt -> HId_t -> HId_t -> HId_t -> CString -> [Arg] -> IO HErr_t
h5e_push2 err_stack file func line cls_id maj_id min_id fmt [] =
    h5e_push2_no_varargs err_stack file func line cls_id maj_id min_id fmt
h5e_push2 (HId_t err_stack) file func line (HId_t cls_id) (HId_t maj_id) (HId_t min_id) fmt varargs =
    callFFI p_H5Epush2 retHErr_t args
    where 
        argHId_t = arg#type hid_t
        retHErr_t = fmap HErr_t (ret#type herr_t)

        args = argHId_t err_stack : argPtr file : argPtr func : argCUInt line
             : argHId_t cls_id : argHId_t maj_id : argHId_t min_id : argPtr fmt
             : varargs

foreign import ccall "H5Epush2"
    h5e_push2_no_varargs :: HId_t -> CString -> CString -> CUInt -> HId_t -> HId_t -> HId_t -> CString -> IO HErr_t
foreign import ccall "&H5Epush2"
    p_H5Epush2 :: FunPtr (HId_t -> CString -> CString -> CUInt -> HId_t -> HId_t -> HId_t -> CString -> IO HErr_t)
```

Comment: Also, there is a Haskell binding to C/Invoke (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cinvoke), but I've always had a better impression of libffi personally.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that's possible.  You can, however, make several foreign imports of the same C function and give it different Haskell names and Haskell types.  I'm not sure that is 100% portable, though.

Comment: That's the approach I take, as well.

Comment: it is not officially supported by the FFI spec, although we go to some trouble in GHC to make sure it works (the x86_64 ABI in particular makes binding to varargs functions a bit of a pain).

Comment: From the Haskell 2010 spec (8.5.1): "Note that for a C function defined to accept a variable number of arguments, all arguments beyond the explicitly typed arguments suffer argument promotion. However, because C permits the calling convention to be different for such functions, a Haskell system will, in general, not be able to make use of variable argument functions. Hence, their use is deprecated in portable code."

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of GHC you can use the `CApiFFI` extension to import variable-argument C functions.

[GHC Users' Guide - The CAPI calling convention](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ffi-chap.html#the-capi-calling-convention)

Answer (score 0):

https://nek0.eu/posts/2016-04-19-Interfacing-variadic-functions-from-Haskell.html

I confess I am a Haskell aficionado. Whenever I program something for pleasure, I usually prefer this language because of its elegance.

Currently I am working on Haskell bindings to the GEGL library. The motivation behind this my desire to dabble in Game development and I have the need for a library to draw on SDL Surfaces. I am obviously not really a fan of the easy solutions and I try to learn new things. Like using the Haskell FFI.

While writing the bindings I encountered the problem, that GEGL exposes variadic functions in its header which I need to interface. This poses a serious Problem for Haskell because the number of function arguments has to be constant. There is simply no way defining a function without knowing how many arguments it has and of what type each argument is. This stays true even for my solution. The only reason my solution works is that I can limit the cases how to interface these variadic functions to a manageable amount.

To build my bindings I do not use the standard FFI of Haskell, but the Haskell library inline-c to call the C functions directly without using rigid bindings. This is achieved in inline-c by wrapping the function call into a QuasiQuoter. As I said earlier, this still requires you to write a QuasiQuoter for every case this function gets called, but you don’t have to clutter your code with foreign import ccall declarations.

For limiting your cases I recommend using a sum type as a function argument. A sum type is a type which has multiple constructors. You can have a constructor for each case you need to interface and distinguish between them using Haskell’s pattern matching. You can see an example on how to make all this [in my bindings](https://github.com/nek0/gegl/blob/a393f8651c1c00a42e24ee475e39089b66488e4c/src/GEGL/FFI/Node.hs).